# SELECT WHERE attribute = form control value finds no records

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm getting back into Access SQL and I seem to be stuck at a simple step. I'm simply trying to INSERT transactions into a log table with data from two tables. The WHERE clause is based two comboboxes on a form that pulls from two tables. Somehow my SELECT statement is not finding any records.

So far there are only 3 tables. The two source tables Suppliers and TransType and a log table Transactions. I have searched all over for basic help and somehow haven't found this specific case. I'm guessing that I have a syntax problem or data type problem, but I have checked both to the best of my ability and saw no issues.

```
INSERT INTO Transactions ( PrevScore, NewScore, SupplierCode, TransTime )
SELECT Suppliers.Score, TransType.Points, Suppliers.SupplierCode, Now() AS Expr1
FROM TransType, Suppliers
WHERE (((Suppliers.SupplierName)=[Forms]![frmRecordEvent]![txtSupName]) AND ((TransType.Type)=[Forms]![frmRecordEvent]![txtTrans]));
```

When I run the code either straight from the query or via a button on the form with:

DoCmd.OpenQuery ("qryInsertTransaction")

I get the message "you are about to append 0 rows". I just don't see how its possible to find 0 rows when the data is directly tied to the source in the form...

PS. Neither fields are PK's and even when I changed them to PK it didn't work either.

UPDATE: Thanks to the suggestion to look into the Column property. I ended up changing my WHERE statement to reference the PK's of their respective tables which even though I found documentation saying that the first column is 0 and the second is 1, I have the Bound Column set to 1. Thanks all!

```
INSERT INTO Transactions ( PrevScore, NewScore, SupplierCode, TransTime )
SELECT Suppliers.Score, TransType.Points, Suppliers.SupplierCode, Now() AS Expr1
FROM TransType, Suppliers
WHERE (((Suppliers.SupplierCode)=Forms!frmRecordEvent!txtSupName) And ((TransType.ID)=Forms!frmRecordEvent!txtTrans));
```

Comment: Do the combobox has any value selected when you press the button?  And why you call a combobox txtSupName?

Comment: Both comboboxes are successfully filling from the table attributes that they are pulling from. ie. I get the correct list in both and am able to pick the values I am looking for. The naming of the comboboxes shouldn't matter... but its short for text Supplier Name

Comment: What do you get when you run just the select portion of it? Do you get any records?

Comment: Tested and technique works for me.

Comment: May be your comboboxes not showing their actual values. Check Column property:
https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/vba/api/access.combobox.column

Comment: @SunKnight0 I get nothing. Same result of 0 records appended. That SELECT statement certainly is the issue but it all looks good so idk what's happening...

Comment: Hm that's a good thought! However, I'm checking the combobox value in SQL which doesn't seem to recognize that kind of format (Forms!FormName!Combobox.Column()). Unless it does and I'm doing it wrong?

Comment: Wait...so you are saying the `SELECT` part of append query returns non-zero rows?

Comment: Just open form in design view and check Column property of your combobox. It should be 1 by default.

Comment: You should also join the tables TransType and Suppliers in your SQL statement.

Comment: Query can't see Column property. Your posted query does not show referencing Column property. As stated earlier, I tested this action SQL and it does work for me, whether or not there is a JOIN clause. Did you test the SELECT alone? @viilpe, there are ColumnCount, ColumnWidths, ColumnHeads, BoundColumn properties but no just Column in design view.

Comment: @June7 yes, in my original query I did not have any "Column" references, I did try it out though without success. As I mentioned above, I have run the SELECT portion alone and I believe that is where the error lies as it returns no values. (my mistake of saying it gives me a 0 rows appended error).

Comment: @Rene I can't join the tables, they don't share any common fields

Comment: Run the SELECT without filter criteria and what happens? A SELECT without JOIN is a Cartesian query - every record of each table associates with every record of other table. So if there are no records when using filter criteria, something is wrong with the criteria.

Comment: @June7 Thanks for the help and suggestions. I edited my question to show the solution. It did have to do with the column property, I was confused on what its starts at (1 is the first not 0) and also I needed to reference the PK in the combobox row source.

Comment: Column index begins with 0. If the value you want is in first column, its index is 0 `[combobox].[Column](0)`. BoundColumn, however, would number columns starting with 1.

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification @June7